# How to find rows in a Table View in Titanium Developer

Tags: javascript, titanium, tableview

I have a table view in my javascript file with Titanium Developer. I have some custom `TableViewRows` and I want to get the values of the inputs in the custom rows I have made when I click on a button in the navigation bar as the inputs will have changed.

This is my custom row code:

```
function createInputRow(label, value) {
    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();
    var input = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        value: value,
        //font: {fontSize:19,fontWeight:'bold'},
        width: 200,
        textAlign: 'left',
        top: '50%',
        bottom: '50%',
        left: 80,
        height: 35,
        color: '#336699'
    });
    row.add(input);

    var labelLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: label,
        font: {
            fontSize: 13
        },
        width: 72,
        textAlign: 'left',
        top: '50%',
        bottom: '50%',
        left: 8,
        height: 16
    });
    row.add(labelLabel);
    return row;
}
```

And this is the code for setting up the table:

```
var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED
});

var cells = [];
cells.push(createInputRow('First Name', rows.fieldByName('first_name'))); // the database extraction is fine
/* more rows */

tableView.setData(cells);
win.add(tableView);
```

And finally, this is my button code:

```
var saveButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Update'
});

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    /* what to do here to get rows? */
    var query = tableView.rows;
});
win.setRightNavButton(saveButton);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
If I'm pointed in the right direction, I can usually work the rest out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define the inputs as an array outside of the function so they can be looped through after if needed.

```
var inputs = [];
function createInputRow(label, value, index) {
    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();
    inputs[index] = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
        // properties
    });
    row.add(inputs[index]);

    var labelLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        // properties
    });
    row.add(labelLabel);
    return row;
}

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    var data = tableView.data;
    for(var i=0,l=data.length;i<l;i++) {
        Ti.API.info(inputs[i].value);
    }
});
```

Comment: How to pass index value to this function dynamically